# Apache v2.2.24 on OS X Mavericks does not run Perl scripts

Tags: perl, apache, webserver, osx-mavericks

As part of one of my projects I need to run several perl scripts in order to display content on the Web.

My problem though is, when running *localhost/~USER/File.pl*, the code of the file gets displayed, not the content. I am trying to run my scripts from the ~/Sites/ directory.

My USER.conf file is set up in /etc/apache2/users/. I also removed the comment sign before *LoadModule perl_module libexec/apache2/mod_perl.so* in http.conf.

Error_log displays the following message:

[Fri Nov 29 20:50:20 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.24 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.24 OpenSSL/0.9.8y mod_perl/2.0.7 Perl/v5.16.2 configured -- resuming normal operations

My Apache version is 2.2.24 and OS X Mavericks 10.9.

If any of you know how to solve this problem, please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to configure apache to run your perl scripts as cgi-bin scripts, or you need to set-up [Apache Handlers](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/handlers/intro.html#What_are_Handlers_) for your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got bitten by this last version (Mountain Lion). The issue is that the scripts I had to configure were not in `/etc/apache2/users/` but in `/private/etc/apache2/`. So try making the config changes there, restart apache and you should at least get past this error.